# Replace words using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a website and user content needs to be filtered before posted (comments etc). At the moment I have a system the scans posted content against a word list and then replaces these words with asterisks.

This works fine for single words, but I am now looking to replace a word sequence and I am kind of lost.

For the example we'll use PayPal. At the moment my regular expression finds and replaces this fine, however if I wanted to search and replace 'Pay Pal' it doesn't. Here is my replacement code that works for single words so far:

```
$word = $words->word;
$length = strlen($word);

$replacement = str_repeat('*', $length);

$newContent = preg_replace('/\b'.$word.'\b/i', $replacement, $content);
```

So I would need it to replace 'pay pal' with '*** ***'.

Ideally as well the space would be a wildcard to pick up things such as 'pay_pal', but this is just a nice to have.

I've played about but to no avail.

To clarify - how do I modify this to replace two words as well as one?

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question?

Comment: I thought that was obvious from my post...

Comment: Questions have a `?` in them.

Comment: Here's a question - Why are you being so obtuse?

Comment: I was simply explaining what I already had, and was just asking on how to modify it. There are similar posts already but none addressed my issue, so I explained it to make sure people properly understood.

Comment: Your task might be too ambitious for regexen alone, at least if a generic approach is needed. You'd have to annotate your word lists with separator marks to indicate positions at which a word might be split up. This procedure would require a natural language dictionary including proper names. If the application should also cover clerical errors or deliberate circumvention,you'd have to check for a separatorat any position of each word you currently handle (eg. 'Pa ypal' etc.) ...

Comment: ... Otoh replacing all separators first comes at the cost of replacing 'offensive' words being part of a harmless (pair of) word(s) ( like 'Es_sex_', 'plu_s ex_penses' ). not to mention performance  hits.

Comment: @collapsar I think OP is not *that* ambitious. To me he only wants basic input filtering for bad words. But you got a point, he could also implement more complex code featuring `similar_text()` and `levenshtein()` functions :) The only matter is *profit over effort (and performance)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newContent = preg_replace('/\b'.$word.'\b/i', $replacement, $content);
```

That's bad. Really, really bad. It's like taking a helicopter to go shopping 20 meters away from home.

For entirely solid chunks of text use `str_replace()`.

```
$newContent = str_replace($word, $replacement, $content);
// If you want it to be surrounded with spaces use the one below:
$newContent = str_replace(" $word ", $replacement, $content);
```

For more complex like "PayPal", I suggest you storing it in form of "Pay*Pal", or other way. Example:

```
$badWord = 'Pay*Pal';
$pattern = '~\b'.str_replace('*','.?',$badWord).'\b~Ui'; 
// dont use 'i' flag if you want it case-sensitive
$newContent = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
```

Comment: why are you using `*` in $badWord, why not just use `.?` as $badWord should be a regex that way you could use `*` for what it is intended.

Comment: You are absolutely right. It's only an example and my aim was to make storing bad words as easy as possible even to non-programmers. `*` is more intuitive wildcard than `.?`.